# What is the best way to update a component in multiple ways from multiple components in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular8

Let's say I have a component A that displays a list of names.

I want to be able to update these names from components B, C, D and E (that are neither parents nor children nor siblings of A). And I want to update the names in multiple ways : I want to be able to change the name, to put the name in uppercase, to add a prefix to the name, to change the color ...

I know I can do this with a service, and one observable per update type, and then call

`myService.myUpdateTypeObservable$.next(myNewValue);`

And then subscribe to all the observables from my component A.

But I want to build a system that would be scalable, and maybe one day I will have 10 new components updating the names in 10 new ways. Thus, I think the best thing to do is to create a global update observable, and then from components B, C, D E call something like :

```
myService.myGlobalUpdateObservable$.next({type: 'name-color-update', value: {newColor: "#123456"}});
```

And then only subscribe to that observable and do the required modification with a switch on the type of result.

I would like to know if this would be the best way ? And if there are best practice related ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're want to do is to use some kind of state store.

I suggest NGRX or Akita.

You would then read your name from a single place and also resolve the modifications from a single place.